# How can i access data from this class

Tags: python, python-3.6, pytube

I am trying to access `res` from this `stream` class how I can do that

```
from pytube import YouTube

youtube_url ="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O1sZcX-BBSA"

yt = YouTube(youtube_url)

mp4_streams = yt.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4', progressive=True)

for res in mp4_streams:
    print(res)
    print(type(res))
```

This code is printing this

```
<Stream: itag="18" mime_type="video/mp4" res="360p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.42001E" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="True" type="video">
<class 'pytube.streams.Stream'>
<Stream: itag="22" mime_type="video/mp4" res="720p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.64001F" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="True" type="video">
<class 'pytube.streams.Stream'>
```

and I want to print `res` and `fps` from this class

Comment: Did you try `print(res.res, res.fps)`

Comment: yes it doesn't work, but i got the answer

Answer (score 0):

This is not documented anywhere, but if you [look at the source code](https://pytube.io/en/latest/_modules/pytube/streams.html), you'll see that you can use `resolution` and `fps` fields:

```py
for stream in mp4_streams:
    print('Resolution:', stream.resolution)
    print('FPS:', stream.fps)
```